# Does Flow ignore defaultProps since v0.53?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

With the following code I expect Flow to complain about the default prop `foo` that is not a `string` but a `number`.

```
// @flow

import React from 'react'

type Props = {
  foo: string
}

class ClassComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    foo: 23
  }
  render () {
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}
```

(Code can be used on https://flow.org/try/)

With `v0.52` this worked as expected but since `v0.53` Flow does not care about defaultProps anymore.

```
// @flow

import React from 'react'

type Props = {
  foo: string
}

class ClassComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    foo: 23
  }
  render () {
    this.props.foo = 23 // Flow complains now with the expected error
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}
```

Behaves the same with `v0.58`.

Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1660#issuecomment-323898823

Comment: You should never directly mutate `this.props` in a React component. I imagine the error may have be triggered for this reason? Props are read-only.